# How to use embedded dotx in Word.Documents.Add() from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to embed a word template in an Excel workbook so that the user can click on a generate report button and have word open a new document using the word template.

The below code directly edits the dotx and allows changes to be made to the template, which is undesirable as the template contains formatting and markup that supports the auto-report generation.

```
Public Sub ExportReportEmbedded()
    Set curSheet = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set ole = Sheets("Report").Shapes("Object 4").OLEFormat
    ole.Activate
    ' rather than activating it, I want to use the dotx in a new Word.Documents.Add().
    ' But how?
    ' wdApp.Documents.Add(ole.???)
    curSheet.Activate
    Set wdDoc = ole.Object.Object
    
    Set q = Sheets("Report")
    With wdDoc.ContentControls
        For i = 1 To 62 Step 1
            .Item(i).Range.Text = q.Range("b" & i)
        Next
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Jake, do you really need to embed that template? You can always use that document to create a new document after the changes have been done and then save it as a different file using Save As? Or are you planning to distribute your Excel File with template embedded?

Comment: @SiddharthRout planning to distrubute the excel file, template embedded. Alternatively, I could access it via the network BUT the macro security and trusted document warning is getting in the way...

Comment: In that case see the code below.

Comment: @Jake: I have put together a small example of exporting a word file from Excel using this approach https://github.com/coezbek/office-automation-excel2word-document-properties/blob/main/Excel2Word.bas. One thing that I found easier to work with is to make the template a `docx` rather than `dotx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > > The below code directly edits the dotx and allows changes to be made to the template, which is undesirable as the template contains formatting and markup that supports the auto-report generation.

To directly answer your question, you can open the embedded Dotx in the following way so that the template itself is not opened but another word document based on the template.

Hope this is what you wanted?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = Sheets("Report").Shapes.Range(Array("Object 4"))
    shp.Select
    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this. I am using the `GetTempPath` API to get the user's temp folder and then saving the embedded document to that folder. Once the document is saved then I am using the `.Add` to create the new file. Also I am using Late Binding with MS Word so you do not need to set any references to MS Word Object Library. Do let me know if you have any queries :)

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, _
ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Public Sub ExportReportEmbedded()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, objWord As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim objOLE As OLEObject

    '~~> Decide on a temporary file name which will be saved in the
    '~~> users temporary folder
    FlName = GetTempDirectory & "\Template.dotx"

    Set sh = Sheets("Report").Shapes("Object 4")

    sh.OLEFormat.Activate

    Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object

    Set objWord = objOLE.Object

    '~~> Save the file to the relevant temp folder
    objWord.SaveAs2 fileName:=FlName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplate

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Create new document based on the template
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=FlName, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    '~~> Close the actual template that opened
    objWord.Close savechanges:=False

    '~~> Rest of the code
    '~~> now you can work with oWordDoc. This will not save the actual template

    '~~> In the end Clean Up (Delete the template saved in the temp directory)
    Kill FlName
End Sub

'~~> Function to get the user's temp directory
Function GetTempDirectory() As String
   Dim buffer As String
   Dim bufferLen As Long
   buffer = Space$(256)
   bufferLen = GetTempPath(Len(buffer), buffer)
   If bufferLen > 0 And bufferLen < 256 Then
      buffer = Left$(buffer, bufferLen)
   End If
   If InStr(buffer, Chr$(0)) <> 0 Then
      GetTempDirectory = Left$(buffer, InStr(buffer, Chr$(0)) - 1)
   Else
      GetTempDirectory = buffer
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: "so that the template itself is not opened but another word document based on the template" -- I am not getting this. Word opens, I hit CTRL+S and the document gets saved back into the Excel workbook. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use either File Save As or in VBA `.SaveAs`

Comment: Then how is using Verb different from my code in the OP? Thanks for your time... as I mentioned, I do not want to save a copy each time the user clicks on the generate button, that way, the user can preview the report without saving it. And when he does want to save, he should not need to remember to Save As

Comment: Jake, I have updated the post. just saw your edited post. quick question. do you want to save the user changes to the embedded word file?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was eventually heading this direction myself, but you have the neater code of getting the temp dir. Thanks!

Comment: But I have one last problem... I cannot kill the temp dotx while the WordApp is still open.

Comment: Yes because the dotx is being used by the wordapp. You have to quit word and do the necessary cleanup of word objects. And then in the end kill the file. :)

Comment: Dear @SiddharthRout, I am really saddened that such a great answer did not receive more than 1 up-vote after 8 years. Please have one more at least today!

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek: That's ok. I never answer for upvotes anymore anyways :)